# Double Quote Autocomplete with NP++

Tags: notepad++

When i write code i hate when i have to double type "something". Is there a way to do it like TextMate has it ? Where it automaticly closes the " ".

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin `XBrackets Lite` can do this. It can also do some other handy autocompletions.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XBrackets%20Lite/